# npm too many local dependencies?

Tags: node.js, git, ssh, dependencies, npm

Trying to move away from `git submodule` workflow to `npm install` one. I have about 60 independent libraries and converted each one into a proper npm module. Now I have `package.json` with quite large `dependencies` section, where each line is like so:

```
"libraryN": git+ssh://git@gitlab.company.local:libraryN.git
```

And there are 60 lines like that. Each library might have own dependencies, but most of them have no dependencies. And they're independent of each other.

Now when I do `npm install` it is pausing for several seconds (building a single dependencies list, I presume) and failing with the following SSH error:

```
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

Doing some experiments I have found that limiting number of dependencies in `package.json` helps. So, having 10 or less dependencies always works without any error. Between 11 and 14 occasionally fails and 15 and more fails all the time.

Looks like it has something to do with simultaneous ssh connections to my local git repository server. Checked its logs - nothing suspicious found.

Question - how can I have all 60 dependencies installed (and managed) in one go and avoid this ssh-related issue?

Thank you.

Comment: I have no experience with trying to connect to that many git repos, but I'm curious if it really is necessary. Is this for a production environment or dev environment? Do you update the modules often enough where it makes sense to load them from a git server? If not, I would look into just storing them locally and using them on a per project basis by utilizing `npm link`

Comment: This might be related: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/3911 -- open issue.

Comment: I'm running into the same thing and have looked over the open issues, setting MaxStartups on sshd_config didn't work for me (Though I might have been doing something stupid)  Not sure what else to try other than hacking on npm myself.  To Nathan's questions, in my specific case it is really necessary, we do update the modules enough, and npm link is a great recommendation which is sure to work for some stack-overflowers.  However, npm link is not recursive, so you would have to go in and manually link the module in question for potentially several layers deep in project/node_modules, as I have

Answer (score 2):

Another solution might be to use SSH connection pooling. Put this in your `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host *
   ControlMaster auto
   ControlPath /tmp/%r@%h:%p
   ControlPersist yes
EscapeChar ~
```

Answer (score 1):

I had identical problem and it seems was able to solve it by increasing MaxStartups and MaxSessions (sshd has 10 by default)

`/etc/ssh/sshd_config:`

```
...
MaxStartups 60
MaxSessions 60
```

Comment: Worked for me. I had to also restart the sshd service.

Comment: sshd_config ? isn't it ssh_config ?

Comment: sshd_config implies this is a server-side change.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to reduce your number of simultaneous connections, which by default is 50.

The following npm config for example allows to restrict to 3 maximum simultaneous connections:

```
npm set maxsockets 3
```

The CLI has been allowing this option since npm@3.8.0. See [this link](https://github.com/npm/npm/blob/5b4e3f3caff1f7ed30281b0b450de056a817bbc5/CHANGELOG.md#limit-concurrent-requests) for further reference.